# php ssh link to CNR Server exec iphist error

Tags: php, ssh, cisco

I am developing an NMS, which will go to CNR and use the iphist command to retrieve the DHCP history of the day. But when I give the command and go to CNR to execute it, CNR responds with a lot of information and spits out
"error in initial response from server: 21
Error 'AX_ENOTCONN' querying IP History database"
How to solve this?

my command : `/opt/nwreg2/local/usrbin/iphist -N someAcc -P somePwd -l -f address,client-mac-addr,binding-start-time,binding-end-time all "12/08/2023 00:00:00" "12/08/2023 23:59:59"`